How to get the date 3 times in vertical from input which is there in B column
I have the date (the dates will be added further also).
When I enter the date in "B" column, I want the output of the date 3 times as mentioned in the "D" column.
I tried different formulas but didn't worked.
This is the screenshot:
enter image description here
I tried =tocol formula but didn't work.
